# Подключение cpp файла

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Работаю в visual studio. Нашел библиотеку с большими числами:[bigint](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/22566?locale=ru), но не понимаю как ее правильно подключить и использовать. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что документация к библиотеке говорит на этот счет?

Comment: там ее нет, к сожелению

Comment: Тогда вам не нужна эта библиотека. OpenSSL содержит те же большие числа, подключается путем добавления lib-файла в опции линкера и каталога инклюдов в опции компилера, например.

Comment: Для bigint должны быть header-only библиотеки, поищите их.

Comment: header-ов нет, я их искал

Answer (score 1):

Ссылка которую вы дали это не библиотека а просто `.cpp` файл который должен компилироваться в `.exe`. Если вы уверены что та структура которая объявлена в этом файле это то что нужно, можно сделать так: Во первых просто скопипастить те функции которые вам нужны к себе в проект. Либо можно создать проект динамической или статической библиотеки, подключить в нее этот файл без функции `main`. объявления вынести в `.h`.

Чтобы теперь ей воспользоваться нужно указать в настройках проекта пути до инклюдов, это делается в **Configuration properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories**. Так же указать линкеру путь до библиотеки это делается в **Configuration properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories** и в   **Configuration properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies** нужно прописать имя библиотеки которую нужно прилинковать.